# strcpy not went expected in wsl

Tags: c, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, strcpy

I'm writing c code using wsl with gcc compiler.And I tried to delete a space in front of a c-string with strcpy and got a strange result.
The string I tried to modify is s = {' ','e','h','c','o' ,'\0'};And I use a pointer temp to point  at the "e"in the string and then I use strcpy(s,temp) to delete the space.BUT the result I get is ecoo,not echo.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <string.h>
int main(){
    char a[256];
    a[0] = ' ';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 'h';
    a[3] = 'c';
    a[4]  = 'o';
    a[5] = '\0';
    char* temp = a;
    temp ++ ;
    printf("%s\n",temp);
    strcpy(a,temp);
    printf("%s\n",a);
    
}
```

I tried to debug in the program and temp is indeed "echo"but the result is ecoo.
The code went as expected in the windows system in visual studio and vscode.
And I also tried different string length and I found out the code went well when the length of the string is 3,7.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJfbS.png)

Comment: Note that even if strcpy did what you want, your code would not print `echo`

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is invalid. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy :

> The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap.

`temp` is equal to `a + 1` - they overlap. `strcpy(a, a + 1)` is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard says that using `strcpy()` to copy strings that overlap is undefined behaviour.

When I compile your code (Clang on macOS, intel 64) I don't see the same result as you, I see

```
ehco
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./a.out
```

which suggests it is using some built in function that detects the overlap, probably because the strings are very short.

What you see is an artefact of the way `strcpy` is implemented on your environment. At a guess, I would say it's copying from the back and stopping when it thinks it has copied all of `temp` characters.

Anyway, do not use `strcpy()` on arrays/buffers that overlap.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, `strcpy` assumes that the two parameters don't overlap. In case they do, you invoke undefined behavior. See for example `man strcpy`.

The solution is to use the `memmove` function instead, which is a specialized function to use for the very situation when you do have two memory areas that overlap. It uses an internal temporary buffer to fix that.

Therefore replace your `strcpy` call with `memmove(a, temp, strlen(temp)+1);`. Since `memmove` is a general function it knows nothing of strings, therefore we have to add a +1 in the end to tell it to also copy the null terminator (so you get "echo" and not "ehcoo").